# How to enable Object.groupBy() in TypeScript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am running on Node.js v18.17.1 and TypeScript v5.

I heard about the new JavaScript method [`Object.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy).

```js
const inventory = [
  { name: "asparagus", type: "vegetables", quantity: 5 },
  { name: "bananas", type: "fruit", quantity: 0 },
  { name: "goat", type: "meat", quantity: 23 },
  { name: "cherries", type: "fruit", quantity: 5 },
  { name: "fish", type: "meat", quantity: 22 },
];

const result = Object.groupBy(inventory, ({ type }) => type);
console.log(result)
```

When I write in my code `Object.groupBy()`, I get the following TypeScript error:

```
Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.ts(2339)
```

I have the following TypeScript configuration:

```json
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    // ... etc
```

How to enable `Object.groupBy()` so that I can use it in my code?

Comment: Upgrade node.js to v21.0.0, as indicated by the engine support table you linked? Alternatively, install the polyfill.

Comment: Isn't Typescript supposed to support that when I add the `lib` option?

Comment: [No](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3956#issuecomment-248515327). Babel could do that.

Comment: @Bergi, I upgraded to node v21. now it works, but typescript have no idea about it and it keeps saying *Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'*

Comment: `"target": "es5"` seems wrong if you're targeting node 21. But I would have expected `lib: "esnext"` to contain the type declaration for `Object.groupBy` - maybe you'll have to update your `typescript` version as well?

Comment: @Bergi, even after setting `target` to `ESNext`, typescript is still complaining the property does not exist

Comment: Using Typescript v5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the PR to enable it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56805. It's in state Open at the moment. Hopefully will be merged soon.

Before it merged you can use a workaround adding these extension interfaces in your project:

```
/// {projectSrcRoot}/groupBy.d.ts

interface ObjectConstructor {
    /**
     * Groups members of an iterable according to the return value of the passed callback.
     * @param items An iterable.
     * @param keySelector A callback which will be invoked for each item in items.
     */
    groupBy<K extends PropertyKey, T>(
        items: Iterable<T>,
        keySelector: (item: T, index: number) => K,
    ): Partial<Record<K, T[]>>;
}

interface MapConstructor {
    /**
     * Groups members of an iterable according to the return value of the passed callback.
     * @param items An iterable.
     * @param keySelector A callback which will be invoked for each item in items.
     */
    groupBy<K, T>(
        items: Iterable<T>,
        keySelector: (item: T, index: number) => K,
    ): Map<K, T[]>;
}

const basic = Object.groupBy([0, 2, 8], x => x < 5 ? 'small' : 'large');
```

Comment: Thanks for this; it works fine for me. I saw a PR has been merged into the next TS build for 5.4. Hopefully we'll see it there.

Answer (score 1):

(as of today)

I've tried with NodeJS 21v (`v21.6.1`) and Typescript `"5.4.0-beta"`

> `tsconfig.json`

```json
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true // you might need it
  }
```

> `.vscode/settings.json` (if using vscode) this is to specify the Typescript version of current workspaces

```json
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
    ...
}
```

example:

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 25 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 42 },
  { name: "Charlie", age: 60 },
  { name: "David", age: 30 },
  // ... more people
];

// Group people by age range
const ageGroups = Object.groupBy(people, (person) => {
  if (person.age < 30) return "young";
  else if (person.age >= 30 && person.age < 60) return "adult";
  else return "senior";
});

console.log(ageGroups)
```

source: [Announcing TypeScript 5.4 Beta](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4-beta/)

Comment: this seems to be the current method of implementation - I haven't tried it yet